# OpenGL 3.x context creation using SDL2 on OSX (Macbook Air 2012)

Tags: macos, opengl, sdl

As far as I'm aware, the Macbook Air 2012 supports OpenGL 3.2. When using SDL 2.0 to create the OpenGL context, however, the context is only opengl version 2.1.

Is it possible for SDL 2.0 to create a GL 3.2 context?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For everyone who still has this problem as of Wednesday, Oct 10th, SDL2 allows you to create an OpenGL 3.2 context on Macs running Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) and up.
You just need to add this code:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
```

If you're running OS X 10.10, or the solution above still does not resolve the problem, changing the second line of the above example from

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
```

to

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);
```

may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13095742/123387 -- SDL2 should support this natively now. The note below is for versions before the latest SDL2 release.

> The current version (as of Wed Aug 15 21:00:33 2012 -0400;
>   6398:c294faf5fce5) does not support 10.7 series. However, there is a
>   way to add support if you're willing to run an unstable SDL for kicks.
>
> Give this a shot:
>
> **src/video/cocoa/SDL_cocoaopengl.m +90 (Cocoa_GL_CreateContext)**
>
> ```
> if(_this->gl_config.major_version == 3 &&                                                           
>    _this->gl_config.minor_version == 2)                                                             
> {                                                                                                   
>     attr[i++] = NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile;                                                           
>     attr[i++] = NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core;                                                      
> }
> ```
>
> Then in your application, something along these lines.
>
> ```
> SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);                                                                                                                                    
>
> SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);                                               
> SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);                                               
>
> window = SDL_CreateWindow("3.2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,                
>                 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);                                                                                               
>
> context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
> ```
>
> I am running 10.7.4 under my Mac Air from 2011 and when I run a few GL
>   diagnostics from a 3.2 SDL enable application I get:
>
> ```
> Driver     : cocoa
> Renderer   : Intel HD Graphics 3000 OpenGL Engine
> Vendor     : Intel Inc.
> Version    : 3.2 INTEL-7.18.18
> GLSL       : 1.50
> ```
>
> I haven't tested much outside of this, but hopefully someone else can
>   give it a stab and have a bit more success.
>
> EDIT: If you're using GLEW you will want to enable glewExperimental.
>   Note that there is a bug in the 3.2 core profile when you query
>   GL_EXTENSIONS. It will report 1280 (as if it wasn't
>   supported)--however that shouldn't impact you from using 1.50 shaders
>   and so on.

Comment: That should do nicely, at least temporarily.

Comment: Please see David Greiner's comment.